# Django in runfcgi mode application on windows

Tags: python, django, windows

I can not understand why project doesn't start.
I copy all project files  to my computer. It situated in c:\python27\scripts.... I copied all data to my disk (c:\python27\scripts...).
Try to run application(such command successful run application on server ):

> C:>c:\Python27\Scripts\project\Scripts\python.exe
>   c:\Python27\Scripts\project\tender\manage.py runfcgi method=threaded
>   host=127.0.0.1 port=8000

and... nothing. App not started, don't print any messages, and don't show next command line. it's hanging.
Try to check:

> C:>c:\Python27\Scripts\tenderproject\Scripts\python.exe
>   c:\Python27\Scripts\project\tender\manage.py check
>   System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Variables:

```
C:\>set U  
USERDOMAIN=letnab  
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=letnab 
USERNAME=Skif  
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Skif

C:\>set C  
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files  
COMPUTERNAME=LETNAB 
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  
C_EM64T_REDIST11=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\

C:\>
```

dbshell work fine. I can manipulate tables. 
I can not understand what need application yet.
Can you help me run application?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `runfcgi`? It's deprecated in Django 1.7 and removed in Django 1.9. If you are trying to test your site on your dev machine, then run `python manage.py runserver` and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in your browser.

Comment: You may need to install `flup`, which is a [prerequisite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#prerequisite-flup) for running FCGI with Django.

Comment: to Alasdair: this project is using Django 1.7.11 (This is not my project. Other developer group created it)

Comment: to  CODEkid: C:\Python27\Scripts\project\Lib\site-packages\flup is present. May be python doesn't know about it?